# numpy vs list for non-numerical data

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Numpy arrays for numerical data clearly work great, but is it slower to use them for non-numerical data?

For instance, say I have some nested lists of text data:

```
mammals = ['dog', 'cat', 'rat']
birds = ['stork', 'robin', 'penguin']

animals1 = [mammals, birds]
```

When accessing and manipulating this data is this list of nested lists going to be faster than the numpy array equivalent?

```
import numpy as np
animals2 = np.array(animals1)
```

Since numpy arrays are implemented as "strided" arrays where each element has a fixed length, a "sparse" list of strings with a few long strings will use up a disproportionate amount of memory if converted to a numpy array.  But what about speed?

Comment: You can always use the `timeit` package to benchmark this sort of thing.

Comment: The main advantages of numpy come in performance on numerical computations.  You're unlikely to see significant benefits with other datatypes, and in some cases performance may be considerably worse.

Answer (score 5):

As @JoshAdel has pointed out, you should become familiar with the [`timeit` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html). I believe you are asking about this comparison:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('[[x.upper() for x in y] * 10000 for y in animals1]', setup="mammals = ['dog', 'cat', 'rat']\nbirds = ['stork', 'robin', 'penguin']\nanimals1 = [mammals, birds]", number=10000)
1.7549941045438686
>>> timeit.timeit("numpy.char.upper(animals2)", setup="import numpy\nmammals = ['dog', 'cat', 'rat']\nbirds = ['stork', 'robin', 'penguin']\nanimals1 = [mammals, birds] * 10000\nanimals2=numpy.array(animals1)", number=10000)
221.09816223832195
```

I updated the test based on your comment. The question is a good one, but you might just need to try some other operations with numpy.char to figure out how it performs. The source file points to a `.pyd` (dll-type) file with a `_vec_string` function.

Clearly there is a difference between those two snippets of cod above, with numpy taking over 100 times longer to execute a `numpy.char.upper()` operation than python takes to execute the `.upper()` string method.

`timeit` is very simple to use for small snippets of code like this.

Comment: And if you're using IPython, you can use the `%timeit` or `%%timeit` magic, which is particularly handy.

Comment: Perhaps more than timing their creation, I wonder if there are operations that are faster on `animals2` than on `amimals1`. `char.upper(animals2)` is simpler than `[[x.upper() for x in y] for y in animals1]`, but not faster.  Does it change if the lists/arrays were much larger?