# Python/Numpy: Vectorizing the combining of row elements with conditions

Tags: python, performance, numpy, multidimensional-array, vectorization

Is there a way to vectorize the combining of row elements with certain conditions?

Conditions:

1. Empty elements get dropped
2. Rows with more than 1 non-empty element get delimited by '\n'

Note that
a) my array has a variable number of rows and columns and will grow quite large hence my interest in vectorization here
b) each non-empty string element starts with a '$' character

```
arr = np.array([       
        ['',  '',  '$c'],
        ['',  '$b', '' ],
        ['',  '$b', '$c'],
        ['$a', '',  '' ],
        ['$a', '',  '$c'],
        ['$a', '$b', '' ],
        ['$a', '$b', '$c']
    ], dtype='U1')
```

Desired result:

```
res = [       
        ['$c'],              # <-- reduce to single char element
        ['$b'],              # <-- reduce to single char element
        ['$b\n$c'],           # <-- combine char elements with '\n' delimiter
        ['$a'],              # <-- reduce to single char element
        ['$a\n$c'],           # <-- combine char elements with '\n' delimiter
        ['$a\n$b'],           # <-- combine char elements with '\n' delimiter
        ['$a\n$b\n$c']         # <-- combine char elements with '\n' delimiter
    ]
```

Any insight into a vectorized approach to achieve the desired end result would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

**Update:**

Due to the differences in requirements, the suggested answer from [Reduce multi-dimensional array of strings along axis in Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51190740/reduce-multi-dimensional-array-of-strings-along-axis-in-numpy) is not the best fit for my use case. See accepted answer below.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reduce multi-dimensional array of strings along axis in Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51190740/reduce-multi-dimensional-array-of-strings-along-axis-in-numpy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even under your updated circumstances, I would not recommend a numpy-based solution for this, and instead use.

```py
arr = arr.tolist()
empty_removed = [[el for el in row if el != ''] for row in arr]
result = ["\n".join(row) for row in empty_removed]
```

Even for your small example, you can already see a significant speed difference compared to your solution in the comment:

```py
# array solution
timeit.timeit("['\\n'.join(sub[sub != '']) for sub in arr]", "from __main__ import arr")
# time: 13.177253899999982

# list solution (with initial cast to list)
timeit.timeit("['\\n'.join(row) for row in [[el for el in row if el != ''] for row in arr.tolist()]]", "from __main__ import arr") 
# time: 1.9387359000000117

# list solution (if you can avoid the array in the beginning)
timeit.timeit("['\\n'.join(row) for row in [[el for el in row if el != ''] for row in arr_list]]", "from __main__ import arr_list")
# time 1.4084819999999922
```

If you want to convert it into a numpy array afterwards to use `np.tile` and `np.repeat`, this can certainly be done. However, I would test if that doesn't cause a similar slowdown in your pipeline.

---

Old answer, for reference reasons

I suggest you do not use NumPy arrays and instead switch to plain and simple list comprehension:

```py
arr = arr.tolist() # if you can avoid array creation, even better
result = ['\n'.join(sub) for sub in [''.join(sub) for sub in arr]]
# or if you need the list wrapping the individual elements
result2 = [['\n'.join(sub)] for sub in [''.join(sub) for sub in arr]]
```

The reason for this is a little more complicated. The gist of it is that numpy can't accelerate array operations on `dtype=object` in the same way as it can on `dtype=np.number`. You get the same convenience of fancy indexing (advanced indexing is the name now I think) and tuple-based indexing, but actual performance will not compare. You can get some intuition here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20942032/6753182

Comment: The reason I use numpy is because I grow my array later in my script using np.tile and np.repeat which is much faster than iteratively building the array. I could use a list here and then convert to numpy array. My apologies for not including in the question (will update) the dtype is dynamically assigned based on the length of the longest string: anywhere from 'U1' to 'U100'

Comment: How can I tweak this to work with array elements that are more than 1 character? I just tested this on my use case and its inserting '\n' between each character in each element (modified the question to include array elements longer than 1 character)

Comment: Here it is: `result3 = ['\n'.join(sub[sub != '']) for sub in arr]`

Comment: @CraigNathan `which is much faster than iteratively building the array`. Do you happen to have timings for this?

Comment: @CraigNathan I updated my answer in response to your comments and updated question.